# I have an error i dont know how to fix: Non-Invocable member 'ButtonBase.Text' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

I'm still a beginner to C#  so if you can,  mind explaining in some detail as to what i did wrong?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RandomChampionSelector.Text = "Random champ";
        }

        private void RandomChampionSelector_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            string[] champions = new string[] { "Ahri", "Akali", "Amumu", "Ashe", "Azir", "Brand", "Draven", "Elise", "Evelynn", "Fiddlesticks", "Fiora", "Fizz", "Gangplank", "Garen", "Heimerdinger", "Jax", "Jhin", "Kalista", "Katarina", "Kayle", "Kayn", "LeBlanc", "Lee Sin", "Lucian", "Lux", "Malphite", "Maokai", "Master Yi", "Morgana", "Poppy", "Quinn", "Rengar", "Ryze", "Shaco", "Singed", "Sion", "Sivir", "Sona", "Soraka", "Taric", "Teemo", "Tristana", "Twisted Fate", "Udyr", "Vayne", "Veigar", "Warwick", "Xayah", "Xin Zhao", "Yasuo", "Zed", "Zilean", "Zoe" };
            Random rnd = new Random();

            int cIndex = rnd.Next(champions.Length);
            RandomChampionSelector.Text("Here is ", champions[cIndex]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what it is you are expecting to happen, please?

Comment: According to the message ` RandomChampionSelector.Text` is a property and can not be used as a function. You can use ` RandomChampionSelector.Text = "text"`, but you call it as a function with two parameters.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Also, most of this code isn't even necessary. Also also, really with the swear?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

`RandomChampionSelector.Text` is a Property. This is like a variable and you can only use it to get or set values.
It is used like:

```
RandomChampionSelector.Text = "You lazy fuck, heres " + champions[cIndex];
```

A method is something that you call to carry out a sequence of actions.
`RandomChampionSelector_Click` and `Form1_Load` are types of methods (in this case Event Handlers for the Click event and Load event of a Form)

Do some searching/reading around the terms Events, Properties, and Methods to see how fit together.

Comment: Additionally you should consider using `string.Format` or, better, an interpolated string like `$"Your lazy fuck, heres {champions[cIndex]}"`